# Description of the residue field at a generic point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How would you describe the residue field $\kappa(p)$ at a generic point $p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ of a closed subset $V\subset\operatorname{Spec}(A)$?

For a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $x\in X$ we define the residue field $\kappa(x)=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x$ where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal.

I am guessing it to be the rational functions defined on $V$?

It would be great if you can kindly elaborate your statements.

Comment: What is your residue field definition?

Comment: Jale'de jaled For $x\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ we define the residue field of $x$ as $\kappa(x)=\operatorname{Frac}(A/x)$.

Comment: $V$ is irreducible? You said $p\in Spec(A)$ and you gave the definition of the residue field for any $x\in Spec(A)$ so what is the question? For $A$ an algebraic variety the closure of $p$ is a subvariety and $Frac(A/p)$ is its function field.

Comment: @reuns Pardon me actually I wanted the description of the residue field in the context of this definition For a locally ringed space $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and $x\in X$ we define the residue field $\kappa(x)=\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x$ where $m_x$ is the maximal ideal.

Comment: Localization commutes with the quotient: $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/m_x \cong (\mathcal{O}_X/m)_x = \operatorname{Frac} (\mathcal{O}_X/m)$. But what are you actually after beyond "it's the function field of V"?

Comment: @Trevor Gunn Pardon me, but I don't understand what you are asking. What does it have to do with $p$ being generic?

Comment: It works for any prime ideal $p$.

Comment: Everything is okay but what is the relation to this $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question:** "How would you describe the residue field $\kappa(p)$ at a generic point $p\in\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ of a closed subset $V\subset\operatorname{Spec}(A)$?"

**Answer:** If $p \subseteq A$ is a prime ideal it follows the residue field $\kappa(p):=A_p/pA_p \cong K(A/p)$. Hence the residue field $\kappa(p)$ equals the quotient field $K(A/p)$ of the subscheme $Spec(A/p) $ defined by the prime ideal $p$.

**Comment:** I am guessing it to be the rational functions defined on $V$?

**Answer:** Yes, this is true.